# Unexpected INDENT while Deploying Ruby On Rails Project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, indentation

when i deploy to a new server for the first time i am getting this error. I have included the file that it references. as well as the error that is shown in the deployment process.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    servers: ["108.235.52.160"]
    [108.235.52.160] executing command
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] SyntaxError: unexpected INDENT
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] (in /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140328165152/a
pp/assets/javascripts/subscriptions.js.coffee)
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160]
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
```

File:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
$(document).ready ->
  if window.location.search.substring(1) == "demo=true"
    $("select#sub").val("6")
    $(".price").hide()
  $('#package').change ->
    if $('#package option:selected').val() == "4" or $('#package option:selected').val() == "6"
      $(".price option[value='299']").remove()
      $(".price option[value='59.99']").remove()
    else
      $(".price").append("<option value='299'>299 Annually</option>")
      $(".price").append("<option value='59.99'>59.99 Monthly</option>")
  $('.recurrence').change ->
    if $('.recurrence option:selected').val() == 'Annual'
      $(".price").append("<option value='299'>299</option>")
      $(".price").append("<option value='239'>239</option>")
      $(".price").append("<option value='199'>199</option>")
      $(".price option[value='39.99']").remove()
    else
      $(".price").append("<option value='39.99'>39.99</option>")
      $(".price option[value='299']").remove()
      $(".price option[value='239']").remove()
      $(".price option[value='199']").remove()
  $('#subscription_tier').change ->
    if $('#subscription_tier option:selected').val() == '4'
      $("label[for='recurrence_recurrence']").hide()
      $(".recurrence").hide()
      $("label[for='price_point_Price point']").hide()
      $(".price").hide()
    else
      $("label[for='recurrence_recurrence']").show()
      $(".recurrence").show()
      $("label[for='price_point_Price point']").show()
      $(".price").show()
  $('#sub').change ->
    if $('#sub option:selected').val() == "6"
      $(".price").hide()
      $(".recurrence").hide()
    else
      $(".price").show()
      $(".recurrence").show()
  $('.email').change ->
    email = $(this).val()
    $.get "/users/?email="+email, (user) ->
      if user.length == 0
        $('#alert_placeholder').hide()
        $('.submit').show()
      else
        error_message = "This email address is already in use."
        $('#alert_placeholder').show()
        $('#alert_placeholder').
        html("<div class='alert alert-error alert-block'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Duplicate Email!</h4><span>#{error_message}</span></div>")
        $('.submit').hide()
   $('.name').change ->
      name = $(this).val() ->
    name = name.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
        if $(this).name.val() ->
          $('#alert_placeholder').hide()
          $('.submit').show()
      else
        error_message = "No comma's allowed in form."
        $('#alert_placeholder').show()
        $('#alert_placeholder').
        html("<div class='alert alert-error alert-block'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Comma Error!</h4><span>#{error_message}</span></div>")
        $('.submit').hide()
  $('.mc').change ->
    mc = $(this).val()
    unless mc==''
      $.get "/companies/?mc="+mc, (companies) ->
        unless companies.length == 0
          for company in companies
            if company['status'] == true
              #if there is an active company with this mc number, then we throw
              #an error instructing the Sales Agent to refer the customer to an
              #Account Manager.
              error_message="This company has an active account in loadmax. Please refer the customer to an Account Manager"
              $('#alert_placeholder').
              html("<div class='alert alert-error alert-block'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Active Company Error!</h4><span>#{error_message}</span></div>")
              active_company_exists = true
          unless active_company_exists
            popover_text = 'There exist inactive account(s) in our system with the
            same MC number:<table class="table table-striped">'
            li = []
            for company in companies
              #If we've reached here, then there exists an inactive account with
              #the same MC number. The get request bellow will always return
              #one company, as should be obvious.
              temp = ''
              $.ajax
                url: "/subscriptions?company_id=#{company['id']}"
                type: "GET"
                async: false
                success: (subscription) ->
                  href = "http://secure.loadmax.com/subscriptions/dashboard/"+
                  subscription[0]['id']+"?paysysid="+subscription[0]['paysysid']
                  temp += '<tr><td><b>'+company['name']+'</b><td>'
                  temp += "<td><a href="+href+"> Use </a></td></tr>"
              .done ->
                li.push temp
            popover_text += li.join " "
            popover_text += "</table>"
            $('.mc-popover').popover(html: true, placement: 'right', content: popover_text )
            $('.mc-popover').popover("show")
        else
```

Coffeescript website Helped a ton Thanks guys..

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
$(document).ready ->
  if window.location.search.substring(1) == "demo=true"
    $("select#sub").val("6")
    $(".price").hide()
  $('#package').change ->
    if $('#package option:selected').val() == "4" or $('#package option:selected').val() == "6"
      $(".price option[value='299']").remove()
      $(".price option[value='59.99']").remove()
    else
      $(".price").append("<option value='299'>299 Annually</option>")
      $(".price").append("<option value='59.99'>59.99 Monthly</option>")
  $('.recurrence').change ->
    if $('.recurrence option:selected').val() == 'Annual'
      $(".price").append("<option value='299'>299</option>")
      $(".price").append("<option value='239'>239</option>")
      $(".price").append("<option value='199'>199</option>")
      $(".price option[value='39.99']").remove()
    else
      $(".price").append("<option value='39.99'>39.99</option>")
      $(".price option[value='299']").remove()
      $(".price option[value='239']").remove()
      $(".price option[value='199']").remove()
  $('#subscription_tier').change ->
    if $('#subscription_tier option:selected').val() == '4'
      $("label[for='recurrence_recurrence']").hide()
      $(".recurrence").hide()
      $("label[for='price_point_Price point']").hide()
      $(".price").hide()
    else
      $("label[for='recurrence_recurrence']").show()
      $(".recurrence").show()
      $("label[for='price_point_Price point']").show()
      $(".price").show()
  $('#sub').change ->
    if $('#sub option:selected').val() == "6"
      $(".price").hide()
      $(".recurrence").hide()
    else
      $(".price").show()
      $(".recurrence").show()
  $('.email').change ->
    email = $(this).val()
    $.get "/users/?email="+email, (user) ->
      if user.length == 0
        $('#alert_placeholder').hide()
        $('.submit').show()
      else
        error_message = "This email address is already in use."
        $('#alert_placeholder').show()
        $('#alert_placeholder').
        html("<div class='alert alert-error alert-block'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Duplicate Email!</h4><span>#{error_message}</span></div>")
        $('.submit').hide()
   $('.name').change ->
      name = $(this).val() ->
        name = name.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
        if $(this).name.val()
          $('#alert_placeholder').hide()
          $('.submit').show()
        else
          error_message = "No comma's allowed in form."
          $('#alert_placeholder').show()
          $('#alert_placeholder').
          html("<div class='alert alert-error alert-block'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Comma Error!</h4><span>#{error_message}</span></div>")
          $('.submit').hide()
  $('.mc').change ->
    mc = $(this).val()
    unless mc==''
      $.get "/companies/?mc="+mc, (companies) ->
        unless companies.length == 0
          for company in companies
            if company['status'] == true
              #if there is an active company with this mc number, then we throw
              #an error instructing the Sales Agent to refer the customer to an
              #Account Manager.
              error_message="This company has an active account in loadmax. Please refer the customer to an Account Manager"
              $('#alert_placeholder').
              html("<div class='alert alert-error alert-block'><h4 class='alert-heading'>Active Company Error!</h4><span>#{error_message}</span></div>")
              active_company_exists = true
            unless active_company_exists
              popover_text = 'There exist inactive account(s) in our system with the
              same MC number:<table class="table table-striped">'
              li = []
              for company in companies
                #If we've reached here, then there exists an inactive account with
                #the same MC number. The get request bellow will always return
                #one company, as should be obvious.
                temp = ''
                $.ajax
                  url: "/subscriptions?company_id=#{company['id']}"
                  type: "GET"
                  async: false
                  success: (subscription) ->
                    href = "http://secure.loadmax.com/subscriptions/dashboard/"+
                    subscription[0]['id']+"?paysysid="+subscription[0]['paysysid']
                    temp += '<tr><td><b>'+company['name']+'</b><td>'
                    temp += "<td><a href="+href+"> Use </a></td></tr>"
                .done ->
                  li.push temp
              popover_text += li.join " "
              popover_text += "</table>"
              $('.mc-popover').popover(html: true, placement: 'right', content: popover_text )
              $('.mc-popover').popover("show")
        else
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that script should really read about javascript, jQuery and programming in general, there are more than a few issues there. I'm sorry if I'm not very helpful with your particular problem :)

Comment: The syntax errors start on line 58 -- `name = name.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");`. With CoffeeScript, you have to make sure indentation is consistent, and that line isn't aligned with any others. Also, the `if` statement after it can't use an `->` function like that -- `if $(this).name.val() ->`

Comment: [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert%20%22OoooOok%22) has an online compiler that's quite useful..

Comment: You might want to have a closer look at your `for company in companies` loop when you have multiple companies; `company` inside the success callback won't always be what you think it is.

Comment: Thank you all for the information... Coffeescript.org was very helpfull with there compiler there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct meaning of `UNEXPECTED INDENT` is that a line of code is indented too much, but it may also be observed as the result of a syntax error having occurred on the previous line.

In order to locate this error, you should start by cleaning up the code.  For CoffeeScript (and all languages, in my opinion, but that is up for debate) to remain readable and maintainable, it should be broken up into small functions.  The fact that you have what looks to be approximately 8 levels of indentation near the bottom of the attached snippet would make any error difficult to identify.

If the error persists after you have broken the highly nested code above into smaller functions (which I doubt it will; the problem will likely reveal itself as you clean up), you can begin replacing the content of those functions with stubs.

Once you have found the offending 5 lines of code, stare at the code intently until the problem reveals itself.

If necessary, add coffee.

**P.S.**
I have also encountered this issue in the past if a discrepancy existed in the code file between `\tab` characters and `two spaces` indentation.  So if your IDE allows it, either enable whitespace display or perform whatever whitespace cleanup option it has available.